# NeoVim vim-devicons are not loaded in Windows Terminal (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, neovim, nerdtree

I'm running Neovim (nvim) from Windows Terminal Powershell and recently installed a vim-devicons via vim-plug. I noticed that the icons are not displayed. In my configuration of Windows Terminal I'm using Cascadia Code PL a required font to display Oh-my-posh and posh-my-git, however even having apparently capable font neovim doesn't display it. However if I open nvim-qt it does work (perhaps it doesn't include its own terminal emulator).
Is there any way to tweak config in neovim to properly display vim-devicons in windows terminal?

Here it is my profile.json:

```
{
      // Make changes here to the powershell.exe profile
      "guid": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
      "name": "Windows PowerShell",
      "commandline": "powershell.exe",
      "fontFace": "Cascadia Code PL",
      "fontSize": 9,
      "useAcrylic": true,
      "acrylicOpacity": 0.7,
      "backgroundImage": "ms-appdata:///roaming/midnight_smuggler_1280x720.jpg",
      "backgroundImageOpacity": 0.4,
      "colorScheme": "cyberpunk",
      "hidden": false
    },
```

And my local nvim config:

```
"Plugin Section
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
   Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
   Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
call plug#end()


"Config
set encoding=UTF-8
"set guifont=
let g:NERDTreeShowHidden = 1
let g:NERDTreeMinimalUI = 1
let g:NERDTreeIgnore = []
let g:NERDTreeStatusline = ''
" Automaticaly close nvim if NERDTree is only thing left open
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTree") && b:NERDTree.isTabTree()) | q | endif
" Toggle
 nnoremap <silent> <C-b> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just figured that I was using a Cascadia Code PL that just have just enough glyphs for Oh-my-posh, just configured Delugia Nerd Font instead and Windows Terminal display icons.

Answer (score -1):

It is a very common problem with many users after their very first installation of *vim-airline* or *NERDTree* plugins. So here are a few steps you have to carry out to see the icons in the vim-airline as well as in the NERDTree plugin.

**Step 1**

Install vim-devicons https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons using any plugin manager (I prefer vim-plug for this. https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) and place it just before the `call plug#end()` command or try to load this plugin at the end of all other plugins(if you are using any other methods to install your plugin) and at the next line paste `set encoding=UTF-8`
example:

```
call plug#begin()
.
.
.
Plug 'https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
set encoding=UTF-8
call plug#end()
```

**Step 2**

Paste the following code after the previous loop

```
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable="+"
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible="~"

" air-line
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
    let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif

" unicode symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = '»'
let g:airline_left_sep = '▶'
let g:airline_right_sep = '«'
let g:airline_right_sep = '◀'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␊'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␤'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '¶'
let g:airline_symbols.branch = '⎇'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'ρ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'Þ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = '∥'
let g:airline_symbols.whitespace = 'Ξ'
" airline symbols                                                                                                                              
let g:airline_left_sep = ''
let g:airline_left_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_symbols.branch = ''
let g:airline_symbols.readonly = ''
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = ''

let g:WebDevIconsUnicodeDecorateFolderNodes = 1
let g:WebDevIconsUnicodeDecorateFolderNodeDefaultSymbol = ''

let g:WebDevIconsUnicodeDecorateFileNodesExtensionSymbols = {}
let g:WebDevIconsUnicodeDecorateFileNodesExtensionSymbols['nerdtree'] = ''
```

**Step 3**

Download any of the font from https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads. I prefer *DejaVuSansMono Nerd Font*.

**Step 4**

`unzip DejaVuSansMono.zip` and do `mv ~/.fonts` and `cd ~/.fonts`

**Step 5**

Finally you have to run `fc-cache -fv` to manually rebuild the font cache. Now reopen the vim or nvim and now you will find that the icons are visible correctly.
Kindly up vote my answer.

Comment: `fc-cache` is a Linux utility, Windows does not have it.